# How to make a website render correctly in IE (9+) in hindsight?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

I was handed a web app that was developed against Chrome and FF and renders beautifully in both of them. The problem is, I now have to make it look nice in IE 9+, and when you view the app in IE it looks **awful**. So I ask: what can one do (tools to use for troubleshooting, methods, etc.) to get an existing web app rendering correctly in IE 9+?

This is an HTML5 app if that helps.

Comment: Could you share some HTML or CSS? I can't believe it looks that terribly different in IE 9 than in Chrome or FF. IE 9 was orders of magnitude better at rendering sites that IE lte 8 and a lot more standards compliant.

Comment: First thing I'd do is validate the HTML and CSS: http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Does IE11 look better? If so, have you tried `html5shim`?

Comment: Thanks both @War10ck and Wesley Murch (+1 both). Warl0ckm are there any web tools I can use for sharing the HTML/CSS? This is actually a Java web app using JSPs under the hood, so it would be easier to just copy and paste its HTML/CSS into a pastebin or something similar. Hoping to find a tool that allows you to edit/modify the HTML/CSS and instantly see the results. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @McAden (+1) - do you mean [this](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)?

Comment: Yes, it's a shim to add in missing functionality. Depending on what things are missing/don't work. As for sharing html/css use http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a link? What are your main issues on IE9? 
Here are some tools/hints to help you get started (but if you post a link or let me know what your actual issues it will be way easier to solve):

- **Modernizr:** (JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features in the user's browser notably so the code can make use of
  native features but still readily detect when features are not
  present so to handle that, as do workarounds as loading a shim to
  emulate the feature, or not using the feature): 
  http://modernizr.com/
- Check your doctype (if you have the wrong kind it can trigger quirks mode which will make it look all kinds of crazy). I usually default to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) to shim newer Html5 functionality into IE.

Also, use something like [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/report) to find some of the low-hanging fruit in an automated manner.

Be sure to run the standard validators as Wesley Murch suggested in his comments.

For an app that was built targeting Html5 from the get-go those should probably hit the bulk of the issues. Beyond that you'll need to identify EXACT issues that you're having such as entire tags that aren't supported or specific CSS that isn't compatible and implement workarounds on a case-by-case basis.